# Laravel: Routing all the routes file

Tags: laravel, routes

I am working with the modular structure of Laravel, and I have a main routing file and 2 routing files in the two modules. How can I make sure that all my routing files(web.php) are loading perfectly?

**EDIT**- I tried adding data in RoutesServiceProvider file:

```
public function map()
{
    $this->mapApiRoutes();

    $this->mapWebRoutes();

    $this->mapModuleWebRoutes1();

    $this->mapModuleWebRoutes2();
    //
}

/**
 * Define the "web" routes for the application.
 *
 * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'web',
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
    ], function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/web.php');
    });
}

protected function mapModuleWebRoutes1()
{
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'web',
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
    ], function ($router) {-
        require app_path('Modules/Course_Entry/web.php');
    });
}

protected function mapModuleWebRoutes2()
{
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'web',
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
    ], function ($router) {
        require app_path('Modules/Log_in_blog_post/web.php');
    });
}

/**
 * Define the "api" routes for the application.
 *
 * These routes are typically stateless.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'api',
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
        'prefix' => 'api',
    ], function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/api.php');
    });
}
}
```

But it shows error:View [includes.message-block] not found. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\larve\app\Modules\Log_in_blog_post\views\welcome.blade.php)

**But**, It is present in my module.
[image]

ProjectController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

class ProjectController extends BaseController 
{
use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;


public function nextpage1()
{
    return view('Course_Entry::welcome');
}

public function nextpage2()
{
    return view('Log_in_blog_post::welcome');
}

}
```

Comment: all your routes should be in routes.php file.

Comment: Okay, but I am working with laravel 5.2 having Routes/web.php, containing all the routes. An here I am working with modules, which have there own routes file also. and they are not working... how can I solve this?

Comment: check out the modules installation instructions. Probably, you need to add the files to composer.

Comment: I didn't install the modules, I made them by this methog:http://kamranahmed.info/blog/2015/12/03/creating-a-modular-application-in-laravel/I checked them, but it didn't say anything about adding anything to the composer file.

Comment: I Added the RoutesServiceProvider file here, I tried it. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `php artisan route:list`. If there are missing routes, make sure in which of your route files should they are. Then the problem is that this file isn't being registered by Laravel.

Create or use the already existing `RouteServiceProvider` to map your missing file.

UPDATE:

> But it shows error:View [includes.message-block] not found. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\larve\app\Modules\Log_in_blog_post\views\welcome.blade.php)

This error isn't related with the first one, you are probably trying to `@include` a view in your `welcome.blade.php` that doesn't exist.

Comment: thank you i checked it:It shows 
C:\xampp\htdocs\larve>php artisan route:list


  [ReflectionException]
  Class Modules\Course_Entry\Controllers\CourseController does not exist

Comment: I added the image please it, there are all the files which it says are missing. I am working with modules in laravel for the first time, and from last 4 days I am trying to figure out the problem.. I am unable to find it though.

Comment: @Learning_to_solve_problems Can you please provide what are you using to work with Modules? I recomend you the [caffeinated/modules package](https://github.com/caffeinated/modules) for that. It's well documented and will avoid you some headaches. Anyway, now your problem is that your `CourseController` class is not detected by Laravel. Maybe you have a typo in your namespace or classname, if it's already correct, try to run `composer dumpautoload`, this will register the classes added to psr-4 in your `composer.json` file.

Comment: Thank you I checked it, there was no typo, I think I am having a problem with my base controller or routes. I have added it, please check.

Comment: And I am not using anything to work with modules.I tried to add them manually:http://kamranahmed.info/blog/2015/12/03/creating-a-modular-application-in-laravel/
using this method

Comment: @Learning_to_solve_problems Check your controller namespace. Is `App\Http\Controllers` and should be `App\Modules\Course_Entry\Controllers`

Comment: Okay, I will but as you said I installed Caffeinated/modules package. I am trying it with too. Thank you

Comment: @Learning_to_solve_problems make sure to use it in a new project, don't do it in a project where you already have problems.

Comment: Yes, Yes, I did in a new file. Btw, there isn't any command to make a model in the module. So, from my older project where should I put the models?... by making a folder named "model" manually, or in my module's folder itself, or in my main project? also same ques about views too @Gernard reches

Comment: @Learning_to_solve_problems I like to reproduce the default `app` structure en each of my modules, and then removing all inside `app` except the Modules directory. So `app/Modules/ModuleName/Models`.

Comment: So, you are saying to delete everything in app except modules folder, thus the Http,Console,exceptions,Providers and the default User will be deleted. So, If I want to make the main page which will be containing certain buttons to navigate to the other modules and it will be in one of the modules. But, How would I do that?

Comment: @Learning_to_solve_problems It's not necessary to delete the default structure, you can use it for your "core", it's only that I prefer to use a Module as the core, for reusable reasons. Go step by step with the package and later you will see how to optimize some things, but first follow the documentation and don't experiment with undocumented things :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126717/discussion-between-learning-to-solve-problems-and-gerard-reches).